# bash + how to calculate percentage from number

Tags: bash, numeric-data

how to calculate percentage from number

for example we set

```
number=248
```

and we want to know what is the 80% from $number

so how to calculate it in bash ?

expected output 198  ( exactly is 198.4 but we want to round down with floor )

Comment: I replaced the regular expression tag with numeric data; why did you tag awk and sed? Are you interested on bash command-line access to those programs to do the math, or in bash-only solutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bash` cannot do floating point math, but you can fake it for things like this if you don't need a lot of precision:

```
$ number=248
$ echo $(( number*80/100 ))
198
```

Comment: Not right. If we do `number=1; echo $(( number*80/100 ))`, we'll get 0

Comment: That's because, as I mentioned, `bash` cannot do floating point maths, and so 0.8 gets truncated to 0.  If you want one decimal place of precision, `$((1*80/10))` returns 8, which gives you the integer part of (10*`number`) for you to do with what you will.  These truncation errors are specifically why I included the proviso "if you don't need a lot of precision" in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Bash itself is unable to deal with floating point math.
The best bet is to use `bc` like this:

```
$ bc <<<"248*80/100"
198
```

The shell (bash, sh) is able to calculate only integers:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $((248*80/100))'
198
```

The ksh93 is able to deal with floating point math:

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $((248*0.8))'
198.4
```

And with a format for 0 decimals:

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%.0f\n" "$((248*0.8))"'
```

zsh does it differently:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((248*0.8))'
198.40000000000001
```

But will fall to the correct value if formatted:

```
$ zsh -c 'printf "%.0f\n" "$((248*0.8))"'
198
```

Also, awk could do it:

```
$ awk -vn=248 'BEGIN{print(n*0.8)}'
198.4
```

Or, with zero decimals:

```
$ awk -vn=248 'BEGIN{printf("%.0f\n",n*0.8)}'
198
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72551/discussion-between-isaac-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: your AWK solution is on point sir!

Answer (score 1):

With **`awk`** expression:

```
$ number=248
$ awk -v n="$number" 'BEGIN{ print int(n*0.8) }'
198
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `p` and `n` are positive, and `p*n + 100` doesn't overflow the maximum integer, `p` percent of `n` is

rounding down:

```
$(( p*n / 100 ))
```

rounding to nearest, half rounds up:

```
$(( (p*n+50) / 100 ))
```

rounding up:

```
$(( (p*n+99) / 100 ))
```